# How to automatically logout user from Guacamole Webpage

Tags: angular, tomcat, guacamole

I've been running Apache Guacamole for a few days now and I'm just testing around with it (latest version of server and webclient). A user X logs in and automatically connects to a machine with the RDP connection assigned to him. Now I come along and edit the user, insofar that I remove the connection assigned to him again. Means, the user X has now no more connections assigned to him. Now I kill the existing RDP connection of user X.

My problem:
It doesn't matter what I do. I can disable the login for user X, I can set the password to expired, I can set a new password or anything else. The user simply remains logged into the web client. The problem is that I just can't get the user logged out. Yes, I get the RDP connection capped, but that's it.
Now I would like to try to automate the whole thing via the API. But for that, it would be more "convenient" if I have a single user list that doesn't keep changing. I would like to be able to say via the API "Log out user X and kill his existing connections, change the password to a new password and end". Yes, I can of course set the api-session-timeout value in the guacamole.properties, however this will then apply to all users. If I set the value too low, it will be annoying for the users to have to log in all the time. If I set it too long, the user X can't be used during this time (so I can't assign connections to the user, because the "previous" user could still be logged in and I don't want to give him access to the next assigned connection).

So, my question is simply:
How do I get the user logged out of the web browser. I can of course delete the user and recreate it. That would work, of course. But can't I just say delete the user's auth token? Unfortunately, I also can't find any information about where the created tokens are stored at all. What I could read from the code so far is only that the tokens are temporary. Where they are stored (probably only in memory, because temporary?) I couldn't really find out. Otherwise I would just say "delete the token of the logged in user". But I can't find anything about that.

Does anyone here have any ideas?
Has anyone maybe already automated this, if so, did you delete and recreate the user each time?

- Link to the guacamole web client source code: https://github.com/apache/guacamole-client
- Link to the guacamole server source code: https://github.com/apache/guacamole-server

I am grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can send an API request to kill the active connection:
https://github.com/ridvanaltun/guacamole-rest-api-documentation/blob/master/docs/CONNECTIONS.md#kill-connections

Comment: Sorry for the late response and thank you for your answer.
Unfortunately, this does not solve my problem. Yes, I can use it to disconnect an active connection to a machine. However, I'm not concerned with disconnecting the user from the machine, but rather kicking the user out of Guacamole itself. I want to effectively log him out and delete the user so he can no longer log in. Deleting is not a problem, the problem is logging out.

Comment: I use https://github.com/boschkundendienst/guacamole-docker-compose it's a docker compose with containers for guacamole server, guacamole daemon, nginx (which is optional) and a postgres container. If you ask me, the auth token probably sits on the postgres under some tokens table connected to users table, you can try and connect to that container and by cli commands delete the token for that user.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I also had this guess, only unfortunately I can't find anything in the database that would even remotely resemble a token (in my case MariaDB, but that's not important). To me it looks like the connections (whether to the machine or to Guacamole itself) are exclusively in memory, which probably makes sense, after all there's no real reason to store that information. So that doesn't work either, unfortunately, unless I'm missing something.